# Drawing percolation configuration with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, grids, random, lattice

I am trying to draw a site/bond percolation configuration.
For the site percolation, which seem the easier one to draw, I was trying this probably too naive code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}    
\usepackage{xifthen}    
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}    
\pgfmathsetseed{1}    
  \foreach \x/\y in {1/1,2/2,3/3,4/4,5/5}{
    \ifthenelse {rand >50} 
      {\fill[gray!50] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);}
      {\fill[gray!10] (\x,\y) rectangle (\x+1,\y+1);}
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

It doesnt seem to work that way.
I would like a solution that adpat easyly to bond-configuration, ie instead of (white/gray) square having white/gray sides segments.
And ultimately being able to draw an hexagonal site percolation such as

[image: hexagonal sitepercolation]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) It seems you're trying to generate some random numbers, but just writing `rand` will not do that. Have you looked at packages that might help you do this, such as [`lcg`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lcg)?

Comment: I was trying to adapt the code from: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130652/randomized-coordinates-in-tikz

Comment: My apologies! I haven't used random numbers in this way so I thought the mistake may be there. Looking at your linked question I see that `\ifthenelse` is not used inside the `TikZ` code, which may be what is causing problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay here is a starting point for you. Actually drawing the hexagons is not complicated, you just can use the `shapes.geometric` library of tikz. Instead of `\ifthenelse` I found it easier to use an `\ifnum` statement to implement the conditional treatment. You have to be a little careful with the number of nodes you`re using to not exceed the capacity of Tex. Probably playing with the size of nodes or switching to LuaLatex could help.

[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}    
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}       
\begin{document}    
\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={regular polygon, regular polygon sides=6, minimum size=1cm}]      
    \foreach \y [count=\yi] in {1,2,...,90}{
        \foreach \x in {0,1.5,...,45}{
            \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
            \ifnum\a>50 
                \node[draw=white, fill=gray] at ({\x + mod(\yi,2)*0.75},{\y*sqrt(3)/4}) {};
            \else
                \node[draw=white, fill=gray!25] at ({\x + mod(\yi,2)*0.75},{\y*sqrt(3)/4}) {};
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**

Rendering the image with LuaLaTex helps in overcoming the memory limitations. The following picture is drawn with ymax=360 and xmax=180:

[image]

**Edit 2**

Okay here is some code for your bond percolation problem.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[every path/.style={ultra thick, black}]
    %
    \coordinate (xa) at ({-1cm-0.8pt},0); % correcting the vectors for half the line width (0.8pt) of ultra thick
    \coordinate (ya) at (0,{-1cm-0.8pt});
    \coordinate (xb) at (0.8pt,0);
    \coordinate (yb) at (0,0.8pt);
    %
    \foreach \y in {1,2,...,50}{
        \foreach \x in {1,2,...,50}{
            \ifnum\x>1
                \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
                \ifnum\a>50 
                    \draw ($(\x,\y)+(xa)$) -- ($(\x,\y)+(xb)$);
                \fi
            \fi
            %
            \ifnum\y>1
                \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
                \ifnum\a>50 
                    \draw ($(\x,\y)+(ya)$) -- ($(\x,\y)+(yb)$);
                \fi
            \fi
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}%
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. I'll work on a bond percolation code and I'll post it here. I am not sure what LuaLatex is really but I'll look it up. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am not quite sure, what I have to imagine under a bond percolation, so I didn't really worked on this. I am not a mathematician. So its always helpful to post post a picture beneath your explanations to illustrate your problems.

Comment: @ JMP: For bond percolation, the connexion is made through the bonds instead of the faces of the 'site'. For example in the picture you produced, you could draw a bond between faces centers,  whenever 2 faces are connected (ie have same color) and you'll end up with a triangular lattice (the dual). Here's an example with the square lattice that i found in wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory#/media/File:Bond_percolation_p_51.png

Comment: This is definetely a more complex task, since you need to evaluate the neighboring nodes, whose values have to be stored somewhere, before drawing the bonds. Need to think about that.

Comment: Sorry, i have been confusing. Each bond is independently open or closed (black or white). The site or bond configuration doesn't have to be linked in probability.

Comment: This is not that complicated then. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach to percolation in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) using a square lattice, and a recursive routine to find the edges connected to a random node.   There are almost certainly more efficient ways to code this, but I was trying to make it as simple as possible.  You could use similar techniques to explore a hexagonal grid.

[image]

Searching through the list of nodes gets a bit slow when `n>20` and `p>0.5`.  If you have plenty of patience it will work, but for `n>32` you should use `-numbersystem=double` as a command line option to `mpost`.

```
prologues := 3;
outputtemplate := "%j%c.eps";

% recursive function to mark the connections from a given node
% 
% global variables: 
% - edges[] - list of edges as node pairs
% - e       - the number of edges (counting from 1)
% - wet[]   - boolean to show if we have marked an edge with blue already
% 
% note that we only mark an edge if the current node is the head
%
vardef mark_connections_from(expr node) = 
   save head, tail; numeric head, tail;
   for i=1 upto e:
      if not wet[i]:
          head := xpart edges[i];
          tail := ypart edges[i];
          if node=head:
             draw put(head)--put(tail) withcolor blue;
             wet[i] := true;
             mark_connections_from(tail);
          elseif node=tail:
             mark_connections_from(head);
          fi
      fi
   endfor
enddef;

% convert a node number to an appropriately scaled (x,y) pair
% global variable: u - unit distance
vardef put(expr i) = (i mod n, floor (i/n)) scaled u enddef; 

beginfig(1);
% set parameters: 
% n = make an n*n lattice
% p = probability of adjacent nodes being connected
numeric n, p;
n = 16;
p = .50;

% Create a list of edges using parameters n and p
% being careful to confine the edges to the square.
% Each edge is stored as a pair of node numbers.
pair edges[]; numeric e; e = 0;
for i=0 upto n*n-1:
    if (i mod n < n-1) and (uniformdeviate 1 < p):
        edges[incr e] = (i,i+1);
    fi
    if (i < n*(n-1)) and (uniformdeviate 1 < p):
        edges[incr e] = (i,i+n);
    fi
endfor

% mark all the edges with the "dry" color to start with
numeric u; u = 5mm; % unit distance between nodes
boolean wet[];
numeric head,tail;
for i=1 upto e:
   head := xpart edges[i];
   tail := ypart edges[i];
   draw put(head) -- put(tail) withcolor .6[red,white];
   wet[i] := false;
endfor

% pick a node at random from the list of edges
% and mark it with a blue circle
numeric start;
start = xpart edges[floor uniformdeviate e];
draw fullcircle scaled 6 shifted put(start) withcolor blue;

% recursively mark the connection from start as "wet"
mark_connections_from(start);

% add a neat dot on each node in the lattice
for i=0 upto n-1:
  for j=0 upto n-1:
     drawdot (i,j) scaled u withpen pencircle scaled 2;
  endfor
endfor

% add a margin all round
setbounds currentpicture to unitsquare scaled (u*n+u) shifted -(u,u);

endfig;
end.
```