# Site Percolation Diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was trying to create an Oriented Site Percolation diagram, following a similar method to this question: [Drawing percolation configuration with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308017/drawing-percolation-configuration-with-tikz).
The idea is that each coordinate on a rotated lattice is "open" with some probability (I've used 1/2 here). Then for each "open" coordinate we draw a path between them if (x',n') = (x+1,n+1) or (x-1,n+1) is also open.

So far I've managed to draw the lattice of points, and have attempted to then create a list of open points and loop through the lattice testing the condition for a path between them.
The lattice is the first half, ignoring the \gdef and \xdef lines and using

```
\ifnum\pgfmathresult=0{\draw node[fill,circle,minimum size=0.2cm](\x,\n) {};}
```

I feel like I've misunderstood how to create lists in TikZ which is at the heart of why this doesn't seem to be working.

I would be very thankful of any help or a solution!

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\gdef\opennodes{}

\foreach \n in {1,2,...,50}{
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,50}{

        \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
        \ifnum\a>50 % probability
        \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x+\n,2))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0{node[fill,circle,minimum size=0.2cm](\x,\n) at (\x,\n) {};}
        \xdef\opennodes{\opennodes (\x,\n),}
        \fi
    \fi
    }
}

\foreach \n in {1,2,...,50}{
    \foreach \x in {1,2,...,50}{
        \if (\x,\n) in \opennodes and (\x+1,\n+1) in \opennodes
            \draw ((\x,\n) -- (\x+1,\n+1))
        \if (\x,\n) in \opennodes and (\x-1,\n+1) in \opennodes
            \draw ((\x,\n) -- (\x-1,\n+1))
        \fi
    }
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is now more like an answer. Since you only compare `n` and `n+1`, I'd write this in one loop. This also allows for simpler checking since one does not have to loop over all nodes, and one only has to store one coordinate. Notice also that your `\if (\x,\n) in \opennodes and (\x+1,\n+1) in \opennodes` statements evaluated to false. Finally, it might be better to let LaTeX relax a bit after `\ifnum` comparisons.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\PrevNode{0}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\gdef\opennodes{}
\gdef\OldOpenNodes{}

\foreach \n in {1,2,...,50}{
    \gdef\opennodes{-5}
    \foreach \x [count=\nx] in {1,2,...,50}{
        \def\PrevNode{0}
        \pgfmathrandominteger{\a}{1}{100}
        \ifnum\a>50\relax % probability
        \pgfmathparse{int(mod(\x+\n,2))}
        \ifnum\pgfmathresult=0\relax%
            {\node[fill,circle,minimum size=0.2cm](\x,\n) at (\x,\n) {};}
            \xdef\opennodes{\opennodes,\x}
            \foreach \Node in \OldOpenNodes {
            %\typeout{1:\Node}
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xDiffOne}{\x-\Node}
            \ifnum\xDiffOne=2\relax
                \def\PrevNode{1}
            \fi
            \ifnum\xDiffOne=1\relax
                \draw (\x-1,\n-1) -- (\x,\n);   
                \ifnum\PrevNode=1\relax 
                    \draw(\x-2,\n-1) -- (\x,\n);
                \fi
            \fi 
            }   
        \fi
    \fi
    }
    \xdef\OldOpenNodes{\opennodes}
%   \typeout{\n:\OldOpenNodes}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Let me also remark that one could simplify the code by replacing the check whether `\x+\n` is even by choosing more appropriate boundary conditions for `\x`, i.e. 1 if `\n` is odd and 2 if `\n` is even, and take the step size to be 2.